# How can I filter posts by tag on the fly

Tags: categories, filters, tags

I need to create a catalog of posts that use lots of categories and sub categories but that can be filtered by tags. I have created a custom post type and assigned custom categories and tags to it. All working. So now I create the posts: 
Item 1 in SPORT > GOLF >> CLUBS with a tag USA and 
Item 2 in SPORT > GOLF >> CLUBS with a tag GERMANY.

If I go to mydomain/my-category/clubs  Both Item 1 and Item 2 are there. Great.

If I go to mydomain/my-category/clubs?my-tags=usa only Item 1 shows. Great.

If I go to mydomain/my-category/clubs?my-tags=germany only Item 2 shows. Great.

Now, I have created a custom page template that displays a list of categories from my-category taxonomy.

So it shows

- SPORT

  - GOLF

    - CLUBS

What I want to do is add a dynamic drop down menu of my-tags (Countries) so that when a user selects one of them say USA and CLUBS, it filters only the posts with those tags. ie adds `?my-tags=usa` to the end of the category's URL.

Can somebody please help me out here before my boss chews my face off.

Answer (score 1):

Are you not looking for a simple widget like [Cat + Tag Filter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cat-tag-filter-widget/)?

This plugin gives your visitors an ability to filter all your posts by a category or/and tag.

Comment: Hi @Mark, Thanks for that. Yes that could work! Great, I can save face.